# Displaying a <video> in a <canvas> in another window - how do I achieve the full frame rate?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-canvas

I have a video playing in a `video` element in my main window. I would like to display the video in a `cavas` in a window I `open()` with JavaScript. (The original `video` element will be hidden, but it will still be responsble for playing the sound.)

I'm doing it like this.

```
<video id='video' style='display: none;' autoplay>
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type='video/webm' />
  <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg' />
</video>
```

I open a new window and create a `canvas` element. Then I add a callback for each `timeupdate` event of the video in the main window. When this runs I copy the current frame of video to the canvas.

```
video.addEventListener("play", function() {
  var child = open("/echo/html/", "width=" + video.videoWidth + ",height=" + video.videoHeight);

  child.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var canvas = child.document.createElement("canvas"),
        g2d = canvas.getContext("2d");

    canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
    canvas.height = video.videoHeight;

    child.document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
      g2d.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    });
  });
});
```

You can see this working [here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BVM2/1/) but it doesn't run smoothly. It seems like the function for `timeupdate` will not be called every time the frame changes. It is called less often.

How can I display the video in the external window at its full quality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timeupdate() is designed for displaying video run-time and indeed may not run for every frame.

To have smooth animation loop, animate it using `requestAnimationFrame()` loop on the consumer side

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

For each requestAnimationFrame call pull over the new video frame.

Comment: Thank you, this is very informative! It's too bad that I can't respond specifically to each frame change, but at least this works, even if it wastes cycles. It still appears quite laggy when I test it, but it does seem to be firing 60 times per second, so I am not sure why that could be. Maybe it's just my computer!

Comment: Browsers are free to throtthe requestAnimationFrame() calls to keep computer running smoothly. You might be just running out of CPU power... check with task monitor. Also please mark the answer as accepted if it's the correct one :)